# How to use Comparator class to an object's data tag that is double?

Tags: java, comparison, comparator, comparable

I want to order my vector with full of myClass its like:

```
class MyClass
{

double distance;
String name;

 public void MyClass()
 {}

}
```

And then my vector is about:

```
MyVector<MyClass>myVector = new MyVector<MyClass>();

MyVector.add(myClass1);
MyVector.add(myClass2);
MyVector.add(myClass3);
//Etc....
```

I want to order my vector's elements by the **distance** data tag.
I tryed to use comparator class but i failed, please someone can implement me a comparator class that is work for this case ?

Comment: Can you show the comparator class that you've tried to use but failed?

Comment: public int compare(MyClass my1, MyClass m2)
    {
       return (int) (m1.distance - m2.tavolsag);
    }

This will do some sorting but fails on the decimals so like:
1.71 ; 2.32; 3.67; 3.52; 3.98; 4.01  .. ETC

Comment: That subtracting "shortcut" that people often use with comparators only works with integers. I guess that distance and tavolsag are floats and subtracting them also returns a float. When you cast that float to an int, it will just drop the decimal part so something like 1.5 - 1.6 which should return a negative number (-0.1) which means the first argument is LESS THAN the second) becomes a zero as an int which means the comparator is saying the first argument is EQUAL TO the second). Best to not use the shortcut in this case, and implement the comparator as one of the answers below.

Comment: Whoops - typed 'floats' meant 'doubles' above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this how you did it? Well, note that there are a few changes.

```
List<MyClass> myVector = new Vector<MyClass>();

myVector.add(myClass1);
myVector.add(myClass2);
myVector.add(myclass3);


Collections.sort(myVector, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    public int compare(MyClass one, MyClass two) {
        return Double.valueOf(one.getDistance()).compareTo(two.getDistance());
    }
});
```

1. Use a `List` on the left hand side of the assignment as you should always program against interfaces.
2. I have added getter and setter methods to your `MyClass`.

The other option, however, is to make your class `Comparable`.

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
    private double distance;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass other) {
        return Double.valueOf(this.distance).compareTo(other.distance);
    }

    ...
    getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Then you could simply write `Collections.sort(myVector)`.

Answer (score 1):

Comparators are easy to implement. It will be something like:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {

public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) { 

if(o1.getDistance() > o2.getDistance()) {
return 1;
} else if(o1.getDistance() < o2.getDistance()) { 
return -1;
}

//they are equal 
return 0;

}
}
```

Then you just do:

```
Collection.sort(myVector, new MyComparator());
```

And you have your vector sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define comparator class in the `MyClass` class as such:

```
public static class Comp implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    public int compareTo(MyClass v1, MyClass v2) {
        if (v1.distance < v2.distance) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return v1.distance > v2.distance ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can can simply sort it with:

`Collections.sort(myVector, new MyClass.Comp());`